# PHP Nested Comments (parent/child)

Tags: php, mysql, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display hierarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662945/display-hierarchical-data)

I'm looking to create a nested comments system - I realise this has been covered before on SO and the net but I cant seem to get anything to work correctly.

Given the following table structure (which I have created):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `commentid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `newsid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `added` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`commentid`)
)
```

How am I able to the comments in a threaded manner? I'm looking for either a PHP solution of MySQL. I realise that parent holds the commentid (parent) of the comment.

Comment: I would never assign a column NOT NULL, when or if it will contain a value, NOT NULL is an exception and should be used when NOT NULL will be the primary value. Instead use a value that will never exist, ie (for an integer simply use -1, where => 0 would equal true) this improves the speed of mysql.

Comment: I had the same scenario in a previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368546/arrange-forum-posts-by-time-of-latest-reply). Shown there how do to stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll make those changes.

Answer (score 3):

When you save a *reply*, assign the parent id to the comment id of the one of which you are replying to.

When generating the HTML, recursively print the child comments of any parent.

Comment: @Prisoner That is asking a lot, could you possibly try it yourself and then let me know where you get stuck? Besides, it is more fun to have a go!

Comment: @Prisoner: There are many examples of that on stackoverflow already.

Answer (score 0):

```
Row 1:  commentId=1;parent=0 (this is a parent comment)
Row 2: commentId=2; parent=1 (this means its a child of comment 1) 
Row 3: commentid=3; parent=2 (this is a child of 2nd comment)
Row 4: commentid=4; parent=0 (this is the "fresh second" comment)
```

makes sense ?